# How can we log basic details of JSON messages processed in JSON file into a cloudwatch log stream which is used to create log based metrics?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

In-turn, the cloud based metrics should be used to create a CloudWatch dashboard that would graphically show the no.of JSON records and files processed for every hour?

Comment: You need to provide more information. How are these JSON records arriving and being processed? Based on your tag, I assumed it's through a lambda. In that case, you can look under `Monitoring` in your lambda configuration page

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ketcham . Yes, the lambda function is used to process the file and the file can have multiple lines of data where each line would be a full JSON message in itself. Below is an example on how a single line of the data might look:

{"skuId":456357,"product":"4GB Red Value Pack","price": 15,"description":"Red value pack with unlimited local calls, SMS and upto 4GB data with speeds upto 20 MBps speeds"}

Comment: And we need to develop a custom metrics for the same.